#  parssing  JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at character 1 

Tags: android, mysql

I'm trying to connect Android app with local MySQL database, but I have a problem in 
parsing JSON array. (I read all similar questions here, but nothing works.)

the error message:

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text must start with '[' at character 1 of [{"UserName":"Admin","Password":"111","Role":"0"},{"UserName":"Employee","Password":"123","Role":"1"}]
```

this is the the code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    new Connect().execute();
}

private class Connect extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    private String result = "";
    private InputStream is = null;
    private ProgressBar progress_Bar;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress_Bar = ((ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progress));
        progress_Bar.setVisibility(0);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/users.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            result.trim();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        return result;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        String name;

        try {
            Log.d("RESULT", result);

            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json_data = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the PHP code:

```
<?php
$con1=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

mysql_select_db("sehaty");
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); 

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $output[]=$row;
}
$data = json_encode($output);
print($data);
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Are you still getting the same error?

Comment: yes do you have any suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your data is not valid because there are leading/trailing spaces/newlines/...

I would preprocess `result` in `onPostExcecute(...)` like this:

```
private final static String TAG = "YourApplication";

public static String asHex(String str)
{
    byte[] buf = str.getBytes();
    final char[] HEX_CHARS = "0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();
    char[] chars = new char[2 * buf.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; ++i)
    {
        chars[2 * i] = HEX_CHARS[(buf[i] & 0xF0) >>> 4];
        chars[2 * i + 1] = HEX_CHARS[buf[i] & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(chars);
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    try {
        result = result.replaceAll("[\n\t]", "").replaceAll("[^ A-Za-z0-9\",\[\]{}]", "").trim();
        Log.d(TAG, "RESULT: #" + result + "#");
        Log.d(TAG, "RESULT: " + asHex(result));

        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            Log.d(TAG, "USERS: " + jArray.getJSONObject(i).toString());
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "ERROR: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm...I added a small hex converter. Maybe you can show us the logcat output of the code? Especially the lines with `RESULT: ...` would be interesting.

Comment: I used  the emulator with version 4 ...I think this doesn't make sense but the App worked.. thank you .

Answer (score 0):

the json you posted is valid. The issu could be related to how you read from the input stream

try changin this

```
try{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"utf-8"),8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
    }
```

to

```
    int read = 0;
    int  BUFFER_LEN = 32768;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_LEN];
    while ( (read = is.read(buffer, 0, BUFFER_LEN)) >= 0) {
        sb.append(new String(buffer, 0, read));
    }

    is.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with part of my code:

`// Execute HTTP Post Request`

`HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);`
`HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();`
`is = entity.getContent();`

`BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();`

`String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
 }`

`is.close();
result=sb.toString();`

`JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result); 
JSONObject json_data= new JSONObject();`

`for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){ 
json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
}`

Comment: This is also did not work !!!!!!
I tried different solutions but I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

firsts in the request code:

```
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
            out.close();
            result = out.toString();
```

and int the parsing:

```
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        JSONObject json_data = null;
        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            s = jArray.get(i).toString();
            json_data = new JSONObject(s);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

try setting the result JSON to "{result:[{"UserName":"Admin","Password":"111","Role":"0"},{"UserName":"Employee"‌​,"Passwo‌​rd":"123","Role":"1"},{"UserName":"x","Password":"x","Role":"-1"}]}" and in the parsing:

```
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("result");
    JSONObject json_data = null;
    String s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
        s = jArray.get(i).toString();
        json_data = new JSONObject(s);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately No, it didn't work!!!
I think it is unpredictable Error..

Comment: make sure that the result string is well defined in JSON.

Comment: This is the String result ,it is a valid Josn array.. [{"UserName":"Admin","Password":"111","Role":"0"},{"UserName":"Employee","Password":"123","Role":"1"},{"UserName":"x","Password":"x","Role":"-1"}]

Comment: try changing to somethin like: "{result:[{"UserName":"Admin","Password":"111","Role":"0"},{"UserName":"Employee","Passwo‌​rd":"123","Role":"1"},{"UserName":"x","Password":"x","Role":"-1"}]}" and parse like in my answer.