# Why does my Spring project return A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I'm new to Spring Boot and json so forgive me if a silly question. I'm trying to read in my json file, convert it to a `JSONObject`, then
convert this to a `JSONArray`. I've commented out the two lines which do
this as I tried going from reading the file to the Array instead. My
JSON file starts with a `[` so I'm unsure why I get this error.

> Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: A JSONArray text
>   must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]

```
InputStream inputStream = TypeReference.class.getResourceAsStream("/json/req.json");        
List<PIECase> allCases = new ArrayList<PIECase>();              
InputStream rawJson = inputStream;
//JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(rawJson);
//JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("PIECases");
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(rawJson.toString());

for(int i =0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    //the JSON data we get back from array as a json object
    JSONObject jsonPIECases = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    // more code
}
```

req.json

```
[
    {
        "PIECases": {
            "PIECases": [
                {
                    "Case_ID": "1",
                    "SortCode": "123456",
                    "AccountNumber": "12345678",
                    "Amount": "50",
                    "DateOfPayment": "2019-07-29"
                },
                {
                    "Case_ID": "2",
                    "SortCode": "123456",
                    "AccountNumber": "12345678",
                    "Amount": "50",
                    "DateOfPayment": "2019-07-29"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Similar question to - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39979590/a-jsonarray-text-must-start-with-at-1-character-2-line-1
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517649/org-json-jsonexception-a-jsonarray-text-must-start-with
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9854678/parssing-jsonexception-a-jsonarray-text-must-start-with-at-character-1

Comment: Include your stack trace

Comment: Note that Spring Boot will include transparent JSON support out of the box, so you don't need to do any of this, just define Java classes mapping your data and use them as method parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rawJson.toString()` does not return the json content but just the result of default `Object#toString()` method of the [`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html), use;

```
JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(inputStream);
JsonArray array = jsonReader.readArray();
jsonReader.close();
```

from [`JsonArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html)